# Shift left/right aligned columns to the center on a small screen using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, alignment

I've got a basic header with a logo on the far left and text on the far right (right aligned).  As the page gets smaller the text overlaps with the logo and doesn't look great.

[Fiddle here:](https://jsfiddle.net/navogel/u0rca3sn/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?random" class="img-circle" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 text-right text-uppercase">
      <h1>Scooby Doo</h1>
      <h3>Where are you</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I have everything shift to the middle and have my columns be centered on small screens?  (logo on top, text underneath)  Poured over Bootstrap documentation and can't figure it out with the grid system.  If Bootstrap doesn't allow for that kind of re-positioning, is there a way with custom css/media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of **col-sm** and **col-xs** to make sure they do not overlap

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zek6vjzt/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?random" class="img-circle" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 text-right text-uppercase">
      <h1>Scooby Doo</h1>
      <h3>Where are you</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for aligning the text, you could use these media queries : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11292

Alternatively, if you would duplicate the block, you can achieve what you want with **hidden-xs** and **visible-xs**, however duplication is not something I would suggest as it reduces maintainability, but I added it to make the answer complete, as it *is* an option.

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw70ndcg/) which gives you this code

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Hidden only on XS, not centered -->
  <div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?random" class="img-circle" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 text-right text-uppercase">
      <h1>Scooby Doo</h1>
      <h3>Where are you</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Only visible on XS, centered-->
  <div class="row visible-xs">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?random" class="img-circle" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center text-uppercase">
      <h1>Scooby Doo</h1>
      <h3>Where are you</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side Note : Seeing that you are a new user, please remember to mark an answer if you consider it the right answer